# Angular 2 with ASP.NET Core duplicating <html><body>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I have setup Angular 2 with ASP.NET core, using:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

I followed the standard setup but the App.component.html is duplicating the html and body tags.

When Pressing Control U (to view source) the html looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ....
    </head>
    <body>
    <app>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
    </head>
    </app>
     </body>
    </html>
</app>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**redacted** 
None of my components have html or body tags in them. the only one that has html or body tag is the initial page

My _Layout.cshtml html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - HotSnail</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <script src="~/content/modules/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/content/modules/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link href="~/content/modules/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/content/modules/animate/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/content/global.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

My Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

The above code is what should be served, now the first bit of angular should be the app.component

app.component.html

```
    <ribbon></ribbon>
<div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

ribbon.component.html:

```
<div id="ribbon">

<span class="ribbon-button-alignment">
    <span id="refresh" class="btn btn-ribbon" data-action="resetWidgets" data-title="refresh" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="<i class='text-warning fa fa-warning'></i> Warning! This will reset all your widget settings." data-html="true" data-reset-msg="Would you like to RESET all your saved widgets and clear LocalStorage?"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span>
</span>

<!-- breadcrumb -->
<ol class="breadcrumb"><li>Home</li><li>Outlook</li><li>Inbox</li></ol>
</div>
```

This is all the components that should be injected on the first page

**UPDATE***
So I have done some more research and it seems to be a known bug. As it says here:
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/662

I cant quiet figure out their hacky solution

```
Here is hacky code that fixes this:
```

> return requestZone.run>(() =>
>   platform.serializeModule(AppModule)).then(html => { resolve({ html:
>   html.slice(27, html.length - 14).replace('', '') }); },
>   reject);
>
> Also in index.cshtml I advice changing app to div because we already
>   have app tag returned from Universal.
>
> Loading...

I'm not sure where that code would go..

**UPDATE**

This also happens in the DEFAULT project created when doing

```
dotnet new angular
```

Does anyone know who maintains these templates as I'd like to post a bug with the development team

Comment: First of all chillax with your ridiculous... we all make mistakes, but in order to help you we're going to need a lot more than this, perhaps a github of your setup

Comment: thanks for chilling my frustration :) Ill edit and put more code up

Comment: There is something that we're still missing here... why do you have 2 `</app>` in the output...

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for angular 5.

I fixed it like in suggestion from last comment on https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/662 (last comment by salarcode):

> boot.server.ts file change the code to this:

```
resolve({
html: (() => {
    let apphtml = state.renderToString();
    apphtml = apphtml.replace('<html><head><style>', '<style>').replace('</head><body><app', '<app').replace('</app></body></html>', '</app>');
    return apphtml;
})()});
```